# Coin Toss Until Heads Wins 2^n Dollars, n = Number of Tails - Expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

A fair coin is tossed until it lands on heads.
The player receives 2^n dollars with n being the number of tails before the heads, i.e. 1$ if first toss is H, 2 if 2nd, 4 if 3rd and so on.
What is the expectation for how much money the player ends up?

The expectation for number of tails hit is 1, but obviously you can't just take 2^(E(# of tails)).
Running a quick simulation also revealed this doesn't converge to 2.

On the other hand, taking
$$E = \sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}(1-p)^{n-1}p = \sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\infty$$
is just senseless...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is the "St. Petersburg paradox."  How much would you be willing to pay to play the game?

Comment: Why "senseless"? This is the expectation.